# How do I make my footer stick at the bottom regardless of screen resolution with a video background

Tags: html, css

I need the footer to stick at the bottom regardless of the screen size with a video background. The "top: 80px" needs to be in the #myVideo class css.
The general Html is as follows

```
<video id="myVideo">
</video>  
<div class="wrapper">

      content

    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
```

The following is my css code.

```
#myVideo {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 80px; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for something like this**

```css
       body{
        background-color:rgb(39, 39, 39);
          }
    .footer {
       position: fixed;
       left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: black;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 17px;
    }
    a{
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color:white;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    </head>
    <body>



    <div class="footer">
    <a href="">Terms
   </a>
   <a href="">Privacy policy</a>
   <a href="">About</a>
   <a href="">Contact Us</a>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Let me know if it help you.**